# go wasm impl simple await raise error "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!"

Tags: go, webassembly

following is my code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall/js"
)

func main() {
    js.Global().Set("testMethInWasm", js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) any {
        r := Await(js.Global().Call("eval", `Promise.resolve(true)`))
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("result:%v", r))
        return nil
    }))
    select {}
}

func Await(p js.Value) js.Value {
    var done = make(chan int)
    var r js.Value
    p.Call("then", js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) any {
        r = args[0]
        done <- 0
        return nil
    }))
    <-done
    return r
}
```

it raise error:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [select (no cases)]:
main.main()
    /home/roroco/Dropbox/mix/go_wasm/test/wasm/testwasm/main.go:14 +0x4

goroutine 6 [chan receive]:
main.Await({{}, 0x7ff8000100000011, 0x410070})
    /home/roroco/Dropbox/mix/go_wasm/test/wasm/testwasm/main.go:25 +0xc
main.main.func1({{}, 0x0, 0x0}, {0x127068, 0x0, 0x0})
    /home/roroco/Dropbox/mix/go_wasm/test/wasm/testwasm/main.go:10 +0x3
syscall/js.handleEvent()
    /home/roroco/.goenv/versions/1.20.4/src/syscall/js/func.go:94 +0x26
exit code:
2
```

Comment: Your Go code "deadlocks" because every **goroutine** your **code** starts blocks because the Go scheduler doesn't know anything about JavaScript (and that it might or might not send on the channel). Your _Go_ code needs to be valid and schedulable Go code. No JavaScript trickery here.

Answer (score 0):

I find def sync meth and run `<-done` in sync meth will raise this err, the key is, when run `<-done` in go func(not main goroutine), it work well, I guess it's because chrome or go doesn't allow wasm frozen main thread

so I impl js `async function` like syntax, impl async meth in go wasm

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall/js"
)

func main() {
    js.Global().Set("testMethInWasm", AsyncFunc(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) any {
        var r = Await(js.Global().Call("eval", `Promise.resolve(true)`))
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf(`result:%v`, r))
        return r
    }))
    select {}
}

func AsyncFunc(fn func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) any) js.Func {
    return js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) any {
        return js.Global().Get("Promise").New(js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) any {
            var resolve = args[0]
            go func() {
                resolve.Invoke(fn(this, args))
            }()
            return nil
        }))
    })
}

func Await(p js.Value) js.Value {
    var r js.Value
    var dc = make(chan int)
    p.Call("then", js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) any {
        r = args[0]
        dc <- 0
        return nil
    }))
    <-dc
    return r
}
```